# Check JPA Query Result Stream before returning it to the caller

Tags: hibernate, jpa, java-stream, failover

My program works with a faulty readonly PostgreSQL database. It uses **Hibernate 6** to retrieve relatively big results from the DB. For that reason I call the `Query` method `getResultStream()` instead of `getResultList()` to get uncached forward-only results.

When a DB fails it's always the JDBC `executeQuery()` call and processing an already opened ResultSet never fails.

I wanted to add retries in my code, but the error happens only after I return the Result Stream to 3rd-party code because the Result Stream is **deferred** and only calls JDBC when somebody invokes a terminal operation on the stream:

```
org.hibernate.exception.LockAcquisitionException
caused by
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException
...
at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery
...
at java.base/java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
...
at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.count(Unknown Source)
at com.thirdparty.Program.main
```

How can I force the early call to JDBC `executeQuery()` and return the JPA Result Stream with unconsumed results?

Here's my code:

```
        LOGGER.debug("JPQL (" + offset + "," + pagesize + "):\n" + jpqlQuery);


            TypedQuery<Map<String, Object>> builder = queryBuilder(jpqlQuery);
            return builder.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(pagesize).getResultStream();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a custom Spliterator that reconnects and repeats the query when it fails to get the first result.

```
<T> Stream<T> doIt(String jpqlQuery, int offset, int pagesize) {
    FailoverSpliterator<T> failoverSpliterator = new FailoverSpliterator<>(() -> {
            TypedQuery<T> qb = queryBuilder(jpqlQuery);
            return qb.setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(pagesize).getResultStream();
        });

    return StreamSupport
        .stream(failoverSpliterator, false)
        .onClose(failoverSpliterator::close);
}


public class FailoverSpliterator<T> implements Spliterator<T> {

    final Supplier<Stream<T>> delegateSupplier;

    Spliterator<T> confirmedDelegate;

    Stream<T> lastStream;

    public FailoverSpliterator(Supplier<Stream<T>> delegateSupplier) {
        this.delegateSupplier = delegateSupplier;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean tryAdvance(Consumer<? super T> action) {
        if (confirmedDelegate != null) {
            return confirmedDelegate.tryAdvance(action);
        }

        if (action == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        T[] holder = (T[]) new Object[1];

        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            final Spliterator<T> tmp;
            final boolean res;
            try {
                lastStream = delegateSupplier.get();
                try {
                    tmp = lastStream.spliterator();
                    res = tmp.tryAdvance(x -> {
                        holder[0] = x;
                    });
                } catch (Throwable /* NOSONAR */ e) {
                    lastStream = closeQuietly(lastStream, e);
                    throw e;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                exceptionalReconnect(e);
                if (i >= MAX_FAILOVER_RETRIES) {
                    throw e;
                }
                LOGGER.error("Failed to get the first element of JPA Result Stream: " + e, e);
                LOGGER.warn("retrying...");
                continue;
            }
            confirmedDelegate = tmp;
            if (res) {
                action.accept(holder[0]);
            }
            return res;
        }
    }

    public void close() {
        close(null);
    }

    void close(Throwable consumer) {
        lastStream = closeQuietly(lastStream, consumer);
    }

    @Override
    public int characteristics() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long estimateSize() {
        return Long.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public Spliterator<T> trySplit() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts by library: [abacus-jdbc](https://github.com/landawn/abacus-jdbc)

```
JdbcUtil.prepareQuery(dataSource, "select * from someTable where ... limit...")
      //.setFetchDirectionToForward() // to reduce memory consume.
      //.setFetchSize(someBigFetchSize). // for better performance
      //.setLong/String/Parameters(...) // set query parameters if needed.
        .stream(YourEntityClass.class); //.toJdkStream() if you want it.
```

Above code can be retried if error happens.